# Creating a dataframe using a list of lists

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list that contains some values from a store (ex: revenue, net profit and sale price), but i have 99 stores to collect those values and create a dataframe with than. The WebScraping part i'm using 'for' and a function to collect. My problem is how i move a list, that has other lists inside her, to a dataframe using pandas.

Comment: always put code in question, not in comment. it will be more readable and more people will see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the DataFrame method built in pandas:

```
data = [["First", "List", "Item"], ["Second", "List", "Item"], ["Third", "List", "Item"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df
        0     1     2
0   First  List  Item
1  Second  List  Item
2   Third  List  Item
```

You can also use the Transpose method to get the data arranged differently:

```
data = [["First", "List", "Item"], ["Second", "List", "Item"], ["Third", "List", "Item"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data).T

df
       0       1      2
0  First  Second  Third
1   List    List   List
2   Item    Item   Item
```

[Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) is the official documentation for the function.